# How to close a socket.io connection correctly in UnityEditor?

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io

It's a simple sample. The server's developed with node.js and socket.io, and the client's developed with unity3d and BestHTTP.

When I play client in UnityEditor, everything is ok, but after the UnityEditor stoped, it still keeps connected with the server via socket.io.

I think there is a thread still working in background. Is it a problem of UnityEditor? And how do I to make it work correctly?

Server code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('User[' + socket.id + '] connected.');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('disconnect.'); 
    });
});
```

Client code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using BestHTTP;
using BestHTTP.SocketIO;

public class SocketIOClientTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SocketManager _manager = null;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _manager = new SocketManager(new Uri("http://localhost:9314/socket.io/"));
        _manager.Socket.On("connect", (socket, packet, args) => { Debug.Log("1"); });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BestHTTP is decently documented, you should definitely read it. 
What I use in my project :

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
    _socket?.Disconnect();
    _socketManager?.Close();
}
```